# anaconda cannot import matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I am trying to import "matplotlib.pyplot". I cant even install matplotlib.pyplot through conda install.

It shows this:

> import matplotlib.pyplot Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'matplotlib.pyplot'

Comment: what version of anaconda?

Comment: also which OS, how did you install... question is too vague as is

Comment: did you try conda install matplotlib

Answer (score 5):

As reported [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib), when you use Anaconda, install the packet using conda. In this case, the right instruction to use (on Ubuntu 18.04) is:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

This will solve the problem.

If you use `pip` (you can), you will mess up all the dependencies (and for instance, the probability that other scripts/programs do not work anymore is not null: if you use [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/), you will have big dependencies problem to face).

**Optional**:

In order to always avoid problem like this, I recommend you to use **Virtual Enviroment**:

## *Whats is it?*

[Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-virtual-environment/) explains it clearly.

## *How?*

A step-by-step [guide](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/) is always useful.

Answer (score 4):

It could be that it's running your default Python installation instead of the one installed with Anaconda. Try prepending this to the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If that does not work, try installing `matplotlib` with `pip`, then try again:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I restarted the terminal and tried it again with "conda install matplotlib" . It worked . Thankyou

Comment: pip is not conda, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue for days, just solved it by adding "%matplotlib inline" on top of
"import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"

So enter this to import mathplotlib.pylot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 2):

Just open anaconda prompt and use either of the below command to install the package. This solved my issue.

1. conda install -c plotly chart-studio

or

2. conda install -c plotly/label/test chart-studio

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Matplotlib is accessed in the `Same Conda Environment as it was installed`.
In the case below, Matplotlib  was installed in `pytorch environment` and not the `base environment`.
Hence when run in the `pytorch environment` ***it gets imported***, but ***doesn't get imported in*** `base environment`.

***TERMINAL***

```
#Installation  
(pytorch) F:\Script\Ai\Pytorch>conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib 

#Check installation  in pytorch Environment  
(pytorch) F:\Script\Ai\Pytorch>python  
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
matplotlib: 3.3.4  


#Import Error in base Environment
(base) F:\Script\Ai\Pytorch>python
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the correct environment before installing.

```bash
conda activate environment_name_here
conda install matplotlib
```

In my case, I had an environment for a jupyter notebook, but installed it initially in a new terminal window which defaulted to the `base` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `...../python3.x/site-packages` is listed within `sys.path`. If not append it with `sys.path.append('.....python3.8/site-packages')`

Comment: Very hacky, therefore not to be recommended.