# pandas and matplotlib not found on my tensorflow conda environment

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, anaconda

I use a MacBook pro-2015, and I use the monetary.
I was able to `pip install tensorflow` to a new conda environment, but after it, `pandas` and `matplotlib` was no longer found.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
```

Below is the traceback of error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import tensorflow as tf
      4 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: install matplotlib in that environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [anaconda cannot import matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501102/anaconda-cannot-import-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this problem

I created a conda environment "myenv" where I installed tensorflow

Then I activated the conda environment in my terminal using

```
conda activate myenv
```

Then I installed the packages/libraries that I need

```
conda install pandas
conda install matplotlib
```

Just use this method to install any package into any environment you are working on